# Maxima and minima of $G(x)=(g(x))^2+(g'(x))^2$

Tags: calculus

> Let $G(x)=(g(x))^2+(g'(x))^2$ and $G(0)=6$ and $g(x)$ is thrice differentiable function such that $|g(x)|\leq 1$ for all $x\in[-1,1]$
>
> Then choose the correct statements
>
> $(1)$ There is at least one point  in each of the interval $(-1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ where $|g'(x)|\leq 2$
>
> $(2)$ There is at least one point in each of the interval $(-1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ where $G(x)\leq 5$
>
> $(3)$ There is no point of local maxima of $G(x)$ in $(-1,1)$
>
> $(4)$ For some $c\in(-1,1)\; G(c)\geq 6\;\; G'(c)=0$ and $G''(c)\leq 0$

Try: $$G(x)=(g(x))^2+(g'(x))^2$$ and $$G'(x)=2g(x)\cdot g'(x)+2g'(x)\cdot g''(x)$$

> For $(1)$

In $x\in(-1,0),$ we have $$g'(x)=\frac{g(0)-g(-1)}{0-1}=g(-1)-g(0)\in[-2,2]$$

Because $-1\leq g(x)\leq 1$ for $x\in[-1,1]$

Same for $x\in(0,1)$, we have $$g'(x)=\frac{g(1)-g(0)}{1-0}\in[-2,2]$$

Could some help me to solve it, Thanks

Answer (score 3):

(1) **True**. As you say, for some $\xi\in(0,1)$ such that $|f'(x)|\leq 2$, due to the intermediate value theorem. Similar for $(-1,0)$.

(2) **True**. If $G(x)>5$ for all $x\in(0,1)$, then $(g(x))^2+(g'(x))^2>5$. Since $g(x)^2\leq 1$, $(g'(x))^2>4$, $|g'(x)|>2$ for all $x$. This contradicts with the fact that $g'(x)=2$ for some $x$.

(3) **False**. A counterexample of this is $g(x)=\sin(6x)$. In this case, $G(x)=1+5\cos^2(6x)$. Clearly there are several local maxima.

(4) Editing...